# Afterlife destination in Nirn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

For Nords, if they died in honorable death, they will spent their afterlife in Sovngarde. And for werewolves their souls will be claimed by Hircine for his Hunting Ground. Even captured souls in soul gem will be kept in Soul Cairn...

...but what about others? Also what about killed animals or falmer? **Is it possible to list down all the possible afterlife destination for TES lore?**

EDIT : To make answering this LORE question easier I added a non-speculation question.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how this can be answered.  Does the lore even address this at all?

Comment: @fbueckert This IS a lore related question. I don't understand why I already got vote down...

Comment: @fbueckert if the lore doesn't address it then the answer is "the lore doesn't say". Just because it's possible for there to not be a satisfying answer doesn't make it a bad question. I am not aware of any problems with lore questions either. Personally, I think it's a very interesting question.

Comment: @kotekzot Personally, I feel "The lore doesn't say" is a *terrible* answer.  That means we're engaging in "Poke the plot hole".

Comment: @fbueckert if it's an accurate answer then I believe it is all that needs to be said. The only alternative I see are unsubstantiated and often ridiculous fan theories. That said, whether we like it or not should have no bearing on our evaluation of the question.

Comment: Upvoted as this is a decent question. I'm fairly positive animals tend to go to Hircine's Hunting Ground as well, Falmer though I'm not entirely sure of, I would assume they worship a deity as well, I just can't recall said deity ever being mentioned in the game.

Comment: @kotekzot We do allow [lore questions](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/can-i-make-questions-about-lore-in-arqade), so long as they don't attract speculation or discussion.  If the lore doesn't address it, that's all we'll get, hence why I'm trying to find out if it IS addressed in the lore.

Comment: @fbueckert I believe that was the intent of the question in the first place.

Comment: I think this is definitely an on-topic question, but it may be a bit overly broad.  The Elder Scrolls series spans five games plus several expansions and DLCs, covering centuries of in-universe history, across a continent of nine provinces with each province having its own culture(s), religion(s), and cult(s), and each of those having their own beliefs regarding deities, psuedo-deities, extradimensional relams, and the afterlife.  There are quite probably at least 20 different places or states in which one from the Elder Scrolls universe might know or believe they will spend their afterlife.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The possible places one's soul will go to in the afterlife are:

- A [Plane of Oblivion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Planes_of_Oblivion) or a Daedric Prince's plane or a specified place of the Daedric Prince one is committed/devoted to, i.e:

  - [Hircine's Hunting Grounds](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Hunting_Grounds), for those with [Lycanthropy](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Lycanthropy)
  - in the service of Nocturnal, for those who pledge to be [Nightingales](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingales)
  - [list of the various Planes of Oblivion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Planes_of_Oblivion) (UESP wiki)
- Plane of divine being specific to a race, i.e:

  - [Sovngarde](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Sovngarde) (Nords)
  - [Far Shores](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:The_Monomyth) (Redguards)
- [stuck on Nirn for various reasons](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Ancestors_and_the_Dunmer) (as a [ghost](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Ghost#Ghost), guardian, etc.)
- in the [Soul Cairn](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Soul_Cairn) (if one is soul trapped in a [Black Soul Gem](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Souls,_Black_and_White) before being killed or was deceived in a deal by the [Ideal Masters](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Ideal_Masters))
- soul gets recycled in the Dreamsleeve

---

From http://www.reddit.com/r/teslore/comments/n4o42/how_do_souls_and_the_afterlife_work_in_tes/:

> Souls of mortals go to a place called the Dreamsleeve. There, they are mind-wiped and recycled into a new person - essentially reincarnation, but a bit different.
>
> If you devote yourself to a certain Daedra, though, chances are you'll go to their respective plane of Oblivion instead. Similarly, Nords who follow Shor will go to his plane, Sovngarde.

From http://www.reddit.com/r/teslore/comments/17y1mv/if_nordic_warriors_go_to_sovngarde_after_death/:

> If you commit to a Daedra, you go to their plane after death.
>
> Redguards go to the Far Shores, just like Nords go to Sovngarde.

From http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Ancestors_and_the_Dunmer :

> Spirits that are forced to remain in our world against their will may become mad spirits, or ghosts. Some spirits are bound to this world because of some terrible circumstances of their death, or because of some powerful emotional bond to a person, place, or thing. These are called hauntings.
>
> Some spirits are captured and bound to enchanted items by wizards. If
>   the binding is involuntary, the spirit usually goes mad. A willing
>   spirit may or may not retain its sanity, depending on the strength of
>   the spirit and the wisdom of the enchanter.
>
> Some spirits are bound against their wills to protect family shrines.
>   This unpleasant fate is reserved for those who have not served the
>   family faithfully in life. Dutiful and honorable ancestral spirits
>   often aid in the capture and binding of wayward spirits.

---

<sup>But what happens to a true Nord werewolf who pledged himself to Nocturnal as a Nightingale, but then died valiantly in battle? Who will claim his soul, Shor, Hircine or Nocturnal?</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Afterlife in the Elder Scrolls universe is a key component of religion, just like it is here in the real world.  Gods and the afterlife are a bit more verifiable in this universe though, as divine intervention and magical relics are a common theme among the Elder Scrolls games.

Most of the major religions believe that their followers will ascend to some plane of [Aetherius](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Aetherius) upon death, of which Sovngarde is one.  However, the [Dark Brotherhood](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dark_Brotherhood) believes that they (and the people they kill) will go to the [Void](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Void) (a dark, cold, plane of utter nothingness) upon death.

These are just two possible belief systems in the Elder Scrolls universe, though, and there are many, many more.  Therefore, the answer varies depending on the beliefs of who you ask, and the only solid thing we really have to go on is what's presented directly in the games themselves.

Comment: Nocturnal apparently binds the souls of its Nightingales to her own plane. I'm sure other Daedra do something similar (after all, there isn't much difference between them and the Aedra with their Aetherius) Some spirits remain on Mundus as ghosts.

Comment: @kotekzot, yep, there are a ton of different beliefs.  I'm hoping that by linking to the major articles people can go explore them at their leisure.  Makes you wonder where a particularly completionist Dragonborn ends up after death, considering the number of pacts you can make in the game :P

Comment: He'll probably pull a Champion of Cyrodiil and become a Daedric Prince. Too bad Sheogorath's position is already taken.

Comment: So, what we're saying is, if one were to cover all the religions and cults from all the games then a whole book (or at least a chapter) could be written on this subject?

Comment: @Iszi Whole (short) books *have* been written about the afterlife, and the metaphysics in general, of the Elder Scrolls universe. The collection at High Hrothgar is particularly enlightening on this subject.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie And to think, that only covers Skyrim - and perhaps not even all of it.  What about the cultures of the other eight provinces?

Comment: @Iszi If you dig, you'll notice that most in-game book authors are not Nords from Skyrim, but texts of varying modernity and antiquity from all over the continent. Many of these books originally appeared in Morrowind and Oblivion—Bethesda maintains a very deep lore that they don't change too much from game to game, though they do add to it. The articles that agent86 linked to have links to some of the in-game books from which the lore derives.